# Why can I use the shorthand `[Authorize]` instead of the name of the actual class, `[AuthorizeAttribute]`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am browsing through the ASP.NET web stack source code and noticed that the `AuthorizateAttribute` class is actually named as such ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)).

So, why is it that I can use `[Authorize]` to apply the attribute...but that's not really the name of the Class. The name of the class is `AuthorizateAttribute`.

I actually copied/pasted the code into my own solution and renamed the class to `JeffthorizeAttribute`, and lo and behold, I can not add the `[Jeffthorize]` attribute to my MVC controllers.

Why does it accept the shortened version instead of the full class name? Is there something within the parent Attribute Class that automatically figures it out?

Just trying to understand :(

Comment: Nothing bad! It's good you found it. Now we can link those questoons together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C# compiler automatically tries appending the suffix `Attribute` when you're using an attribute (which is obvious syntactically). It just makes things easier. From the [C# 5 spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) section 17.2 (Attribute Specification):

> By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of `Attribute`. An *attribute-name* of the form *type-name* may either include or omit this suffix. If an attribute class is found both with and without this suffix, an ambiguity is present, and a compile-time error results. If the *attribute-name* is spelled such that its right-most identifier is a verbatim identifier (§2.4.2), then only an attribute without a suffix is matched, thus enabling such an ambiguity to be resolved.

You *should* be able to use your `[Jeffthroize]` example - it's hard to tell why you can't in your specific situation, without seeing the code and the error message.

For example, this is fine:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
class FooAttribute : Attribute {}        

[FooAttribute] // Full name
class Test 
{
    [Foo] // Abbreviated name
    public static void Main() {}
}
```

If you tried to use `[@Foo]`, that would be invalid - but `[@FooAttribute]` is valid.

Also note that [VB has the same shorthand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y0xyec6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @JGinSD: That's the C# 1.2 specification - unfortunately I don't *think* there's a full C# 5 specification in HTML format. I'll add a link to the Word version in my answer though.

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially syntactic sugar enforced by the compiler. By convention, you can refer to an Attribute without the suffix.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx

> By convention, the name of the attribute class ends with the word
>   Attribute. While not required, this convention is recommended for
>   readability. When the attribute is applied, the inclusion of the word
>   Attribute is optional.

Comment: It never occurred to me that it would be a compiler or simply a languages specific 'feature'. Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: There are several convention based features of C#, like a member being `private` by default. Jon Skeet could probably give you more details on that than I could :)

Answer (score 1):

Because that is the naming standard for an attribute to be used on a class or methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply saying, it is accepted, because the compiler was written in such way.

There's a requirement that all `Attribute`s **must** derive from the `Attribute` class. Therefore it's can be assumed that everything in brackets `[]` is an 'Attribute'.

There's a programmers' custom that things XXXX are often being named XxxxThing, PersonView, LoginController, ReadOnlyAttribute. It gives you a bit better look on the code when you are looking at files. However, when you deal only with controllers, only with views, or only with attributes, it's tiresome to have to always say XxxxAttribute, YyyyAttribute.

Since you **know** that all things written in `[]` are of the `Attribute` class, it's not really necessary to write the `Attribute` word contained in the class name. It adds nothing. You know it's an attribute because it's in the `[]`.

It's just a handy shortcut provided by the language/compiler, for your convenience only, and only available in this place in the code. If you search with Reflection for that attribute classes, or if you try to `Activator.Create<>` or even `typeof()` it, you still need the full name.

And about the problem with custom attribute:

- make sure you've got your `using`s right
- make sure you have added the reference
- make sure you have recompiled all assemblies
- ensure that `typeof(JeffthrotizeAttribute)` does not complain aobut unknown type. If so - get to the first three points
- if the compiler still complains about `[Jeffthrotize]` than most probably you've got the flags wrong. Remember that attributes **need** to have `AttributeUsage` specified correctly. If you specify `AttributeTargets.Method`, then you will not be able to put that attribute on a whole class. You can combine the attribute-usages with `|` operator, like any flag: `AttributeTargets.Method|AttributeTargets.Class`, etc.

See `http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.attributetargets.aspx` for full list.